# PHP: Insert NULL value in mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysqli

I am in a strange situation. In my database table fields are defined as `NOT NULL`. When i run below query it doesn't show the output of `echo 'Data Added';`

But if I change field defintions via phpmyadmin to `NULL=yes` then it is showing `Data Added`.

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO posting (emp_id, title, open, description, keywords, min, max, ip_add) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$results ->bind_param("isisssss", $emp_id, $title, $open, $description, $keywords, $min, $max, $ip_add );

$results->execute();

if($results->affected_rows == 1){

            echo 'Data Added';
        }
```

I want to know do i need to change all field in mysql table and make them Null = Yes or is there any other way to achieve this?

Am i doing something wrong here. please advise.

Comment: Making table field default value `null` if needed is much better approach.

Comment: @fusion3k `min` and `max` aren't reserved.

Comment: @fusion3k I don't see them listed at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html. Where did you get the idea that they're reserved?

Comment: You could just pass the `NULL` in the list of values, `?, NULL`.

Comment: If the fields aren't nullable, why are you trying to insert null values into them? You should make sure that all the variables have values.

Comment: Please don't argu about min and max. This is sample query. I am just looking for approach.

Comment: if user didn't put the value in any of the fields as some fields would be optional then do i need to define them as null in database?

Comment: It's really a matter of database design. Do you need to distinguish not assigning the field at all and assigning it an empty value?

Comment: @404 If you leave a form text field blank, the client should send an empty string as the value, not a null value.

Comment: @Barmar from my dreams, maybe...  ϡ

Comment: @chris85 yes... i'm in confusion...

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the question. Why it down voted. Anyways thanks.

Comment: nothing wrong with the question,..voted up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the column in PHPmyAdmin is set 'not null' it means that you need to have some value in that field, otherwise it fails, so in short your INSERT query would fail and you won't see `echo 'Data Added';` since no rows were affected due to the previous error in MySQL.

As to what all you should make NULL depends on your setup, some fields might be mandatory, for example you may want your 'emp_id' to be present all times in a record so you would make it 'NOT NULL'.

Set the field attributes and make changes in your code accordingly, if a field is mandatory in the database you can take measures to ensure that the field is present before being sent to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Voted up.